# List collection conversion

Tags: c#, collections

give me please advice. How can I do directly conversion from List[string[]] to List[int[]] or conversion to my define object for example FreightInTeritory

here is conversion code List to List :

```
        List<string[]> obj = new List<string[]>();
        obj.Add(new string[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"});
        obj.Add(new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" });
        obj.Add(new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" });
        obj.Add(new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" });

        var l1 = obj.ConvertAll(s=>Int32.Parse(s.ToString()));
```

and how way can I do conversion from class object (FreightInTeritory) to for example List[string[]] thank you very much.....

```
   public class FreightInTeritory
   {
    private string territoryDescription;
    private double freight;

    public string TerritoryDescription { get; set; }
    public string Freight {get; set;}
   }
```

Comment: Regarding your first question, you've almost answered it yourself. All that's left is to convert `l1` from `int[]` to `List<int>` (not `List[int[]]` btw.). Either with `new List<int>(l1)` or with `l1.ToList()`. (The latter option requires a `using System.Linq;` directive.)

Answer (score 1):

Why do u convert? U can just make a list of ints from start.

```
    List<int[]> obj = new List<int[]>();
```

And to add values

```
    obj.Add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

The FreightInTeritory objects can be stored in a FreightInTeritory list

```
    List<FreightInTeritory> FreightInTeritoryList = new List<FreightInTeritory>();
```